# socket.io is not working with static file routing node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I'm writing a chat application. In that, when the static file routing is working the socket.io (Chat) is not working throws not found error in console.

> http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1486739955177-8 404 not found

When the chat is working fine then public static files is not working throws error

> Cannot GET /public/index.html

**The code chat working (public static files not working) :**

```
var app=require('express')();
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
var path=require('path');

//Initialize application with route
app.get('/',function (req,res) {
 var express=require('express');
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/public')));
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../public','chat.html'));
});

//Register events on socket connection
io.on('connection',function (socket) {
   socket.on('chatMessage',function (from, msg) {
    io.emit('chatMessage',from,msg);
 });

 socket.on('notifyUser',function (user) {
    io.emit('notifyUser',user);
  });
});

// Listen appliaction request on port 80
http.listen(80,function () {
   console.log('Server Running in port 80');
});
```

**The code public static files working ( chat not working) :**

```
var app=require('express')();
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);
var path=require('path');

//Initialize application with route
var express=require('express');
app.use(express.static('public/'));
app.use('/public',express.static('public/stack'));


//Register events on socket connection
io.on('connection',function (socket) {
    socket.on('chatMessage',function (from, msg) {
        io.emit('chatMessage',from,msg);
    });
    socket.on('notifyUser',function (user) {
        io.emit('notifyUser',user);
    });
});


app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.send('what???', 404);
});

// Listen appliaction request on port 80
app.listen(80,function () {
    console.log('Server Running in port 80');
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error. My port 80 is busy with nginx, so I set it to 8000 and chat works with static as well.

Comment: `GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1486743833778-61 404 (Not Found)` no it's not working

Comment: that `404` is because of your wildcard route `app.get('*', ..  res.send('what???', 404);`

Comment: I even commented that route. not working. In the network panel it's gives `Cannot GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1486744187480-26`

Comment: @SasiVarunan Same error..

Comment: try 
`var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var path=require('path');`
and remove http completely, You're not listening websocket port.

Comment: @SasiVarunan TypeError: require(...).createServer is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this code works

```
var express=require('express');
var app = express();
var path=require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
//Initialize application with route
app.use(express.static('public/'));
// app.use('/public',express.static('public/stack'));

//Register events on socket connection
io.on('connection',function (socket) {
    socket.on('chatMessage',function (from, msg) {
        io.emit('chatMessage',from,msg);
    });
    socket.on('notifyUser',function (user) {
        io.emit('notifyUser',user);
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('what???', 404);
});

// Listen appliaction request on port 80
server.listen(80,function () {
    console.log('Server Running in port 80');
});
```

Move your `chat.html` in side public folder and access like http://localhost/client.html

Directory structure is like

`appdir
      public/client.html
      server.js`
`node server.js`

Comment: It's working perfect. I want to know how to use socket functions other than server.js file. Because I want to store those msgs to database. If I write those functions here server.js file would look messy..

Comment: Then you need to write all your functions in separate js file and do export. Then in your server.js file you need to require it. Its worth reading and understanding `exports and module.exports ` and dive in to your project https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/